# Summary statistics version problem

Tags: gwas, polygenic-risk-score

I am learning GWAS study and PRS for predicting disease. I was aligning my sequencing data with GRCH38 reference panel. However, in the PRS analysis step, I found that most of the summary statistics are developed in GRCH37. It was a bit inconvenient for me because I have to convert vcf/snp file into GRCH37 which may end up losing some snps. I was checking this database [link](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gwas/downloads/summary-statistics).
Is there any database of summary statistics in GRCH38?

Comment: It's a good question, could you please consider upvoting/accepting the answer by user438383. It's definitely useful IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue. Instead of lifting over your genomes, it might be computationally and conceptually easier just to lift over the summary statistics to GRCh37. Alternatively (and preferably), this is **done for you** for every GWAS published in the GWAS catalog. Simply click on the "harmonized" folder after clicking on "download" and you can download whatever build aligns with your genotype data.

Comment: I am sticking with generating vcf in GRCH37. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ShafayetRahat You'll also need to ensure the scorefile is b37 too

Comment: ok, thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [this tool](https://github.com/hakyimlab/summary-gwas-imputation) which contains some software to [liftover](https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/LiftOver) your coordinates from one build to another.